# Какое существительное со временем изменило род?

Tags: морфология

Одно из существительных женского рода раньше было другого рода. Какое именно?
Кость, тень, рожь, соль, скатерть, ночь.

Answer (score 3):

> Одно из существительных женского рода раньше было другого рода. Какое
>   именно?
>
> ***Кость, тень, рожь, соль, скатерть, ночь.***

Думаю, что в том написании и при том произношении, к которому мы привыкли, все приведённые в вопросе слова **всегда относились к женскому роду.**

То, что   слово ***тенёк*** мужского рода, никак не свидетельствует в пользу того, что  и слово ***тень***  имело когда-то мужской род. Случаев употребления слова ***тень*** в мужском роде ни Нацкорпус, ни какой-либо иной источник, вроде бы, не фиксирует.

Если бы ***тенёк*** пришёл к нам с давних времён, то его род, конечно, о чём-то бы говорил. Но… Появился-то ***тенёк,*** оказывается, совсем недавно (и скорее всего, под влиянием слов ***пенёк, конёк*** и др., возникших  **раньше** *тенька*)  — см. **[Нацкорпус](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F2%E5%ED%B8%EA&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При чём здесь Нацкорпус, если речь о праязыке? Ответ  точно ТЕНЬ,  эту задачу дают из олимпиады в олимпиаду, она мне уже надоела. Придумал её Зализняк, ответы везде есть. http://svetozar.ru/index/id/38630/index.html  
http://liceum-6-tmb.narod.ru/teacher/material/russia/olimp/olimpiad.htm

Comment: Если хотите, объяснения есть в лекции кандидата филологических наук, старшего научного сотрудника Института востоковедения РАН, старшего научного сотрудника филологического факультета МГУ им. М.В. Ломоносова Светланы Бурлак,  прочитанной 24 января 2013 года. в рамках проекта «Публичные лекции "Полит.ру"».http://polit.ru/article/2013/06/30/burlak/

Comment: Кстати, чрезвычайно интересная лекция, о тени-теньке где-то посередине лекции

Comment: _Людмила: При чём здесь Нацкорпус, если речь о праязыке?_ ===  Как при чём?

 А каким образом определить, когда в язык вошло слово "тенёк"? Почему оно фиксируется у авторов только с середины 20-го века (пример конца 19-го века вошёл в Нацкорпус из-за орфографической ошибки)? Где примеры его употребления пусть не в праязыке, а хотя бы в веке 18-м или 19-м?

Comment: И второе: как в праязыке, в котором **тень** была(?) мужского рода, это слово звучало? Ведь **тень** в таком её написании и произношении фиксируется в словарях **только** с 1731 года, в русском же языке ХVI—XVII вв. известно, по-моему  **тѣня** (так в этимологическом словаре Шапошникова). Может быть, это  **тѣня** и было мужского рода, но при чём тут **тень?**

Answer (score 2):

Тень, потому что уменьшительное тенёк.

Пень-пенёк, зверь-зверёк, конь-конёк, день-денёк.
Это довольно -таки известная задача Зализняка

Объяснение можно найти в лекции С.Бурлак, кандидата филологических наук: в древнерусском было так называемое склонение на *о, предок современного второго склонения, и склонение на *i, предок современного третьего склонения. В склонении на *i были слова не только женского, как сейчас, но и мужского рода, например, к нему относилось слово гость. Сначала в склонении на *о (в его мягкой разновидности) были слова с исконно мягкими согласными в исходе основы, а в склонение на *i попадали слова, у которых мягкость была обусловлена гласным ь, так что можно было эти склонения различать. Но когда мягкость стала фонологична, когда все согласные стали мягкими в равной мере – не потому, что гласные рядом, а просто по сути своей, – это различие стёрлось. С развитием аканья стёрлось и различие между окончаниями родительного падежа. В предложном падеже поменялось окончание: сейчас мы скажем о князе, но аканье и здесь стирает нам границы, так что в итоге остаётся только вот эта строчка – дательный падеж, – где есть различия. Соответственно, различие проявляется слишком редко – и мужской род склонения на *i расформировывается: одушевлённые слова уходят в тип склонения на *о, и теперь гостя мы склоняем так же, как и князя (так же мы склоняем и лося, который фигурировал на одном из предыдущих слайдов), – а слова неодушевлённые обычно меняли род, но оставались в третьем склонении. Например, сменило род слово тень: раньше оно было мужского рода, и от него тогда образовалась уменьшительная форма тенёк. Вообще, уменьшительные обычно сохраняют род: стул – стульчик, колесо – колёсико, рука – ручка, лапа – лапка, – род сохраняется. А уменьшительное от слова тень почему-то не те́нька, а тенёк. На самом деле, потому, что раньше это слово было мужского рода. А теперь просто все уже привыкли, что тень – тенёк. В третьем склонении осталось только одно слово мужского рода. Кто знает, какое?
Голос из зала: Путь.